# WPF inheriting interface in view or in separate class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I'm making a media player program and I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMediaService
{
    void Play();
}
```

Would it be more appropriate to inherit the interface in the view where the `MediaElement` control resides and access it directly in the implementation of the methods or rather have it in a separate class like this:

```
public class MediaPlayer : IMediaService
{
    private MediaElement _mediaElement;
    public MediaPlayer(MediaElement mediaElement)
    {
        _mediaElement = mediaElement;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        _mediaElement.Play();
        //...
    }
}
```

vs inheriting it in the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : IMediaService
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void IMediaService.Play()
    {
        Player.Play();
        //..
    }
}
```

I'm not using MVVM, but those methods might be used as bindings through commands.

The problem I see in the second approach is that my view class will get cluttered really fast.

I'm open to any alternative solutions that I haven't mentioned, this is just what I've come up with atm.

Comment: its better to go with first approach because u should not add responsibility of handling media player to main window. Its good to keep it separately.

Comment: _"I'm not using MVVM"_ -- I am puzzled that you would not use the appropriate idiom in WPF, but then think that the _opinions_ of Stack Overflow users about which class you make implement an interface matters even a single whit.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't see the point of your comment. If you're here just to nibble please pass along.

Comment: @PeterDuniho makes a valid point, though. The question is what are you using the interface for? Are you creating the interface just for the sake of having an interface or are you passing it around? Where are you passing it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be more appropriate to inherit the interface in the view where the MediaElement control resides and access it directly in the implementation of the methods or rather have it in a separate class like this:

It doesn't really matter as far as MVVM is concerned. There is no right or wrong really. It's depends on the developer's personal preference. If you don't want to pollute your view, you create a separate class. If you don't mind adding some methods to your view, you don't.

The benefit of using a seperate class is that you may reuse it for several different views/`MediaElement`.

But the view model only cares about the interface itself, i.e. it has no dependency upon the actual implementation of it.